# What is replacement of fields.Method in flask-marshmallow?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I am writing a REST API using python-flask.

I want to do some process on fetched fields before serializing them. So I guess the best solution is fields.Method but it seems fields.Method is removed from marshmallow since 3.0 version. What is the replacement of it in marshmallow schema?

Answer (score 0):

Use pre/post processing, docs here: 
https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#pre-processing-and-post-processing-methods